# How do the different sections in docker compose behave when having multiple compose files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a complex project with multiple `docker-compose` files which get loaded depending on the environment I want to simulate.

I would like to see documentation related to the use of multiple compose files. I have the feeling that some sections are additive (`ports`) while other sections follow a replace strategy (`environment`)

I am unable to find documentation about this. Is there an official description of the behaviour?

I could prepare a simple PoC to test this, but I would prefer to refer to an official explanation to avoid reaching the wrong conclussions.

This is [all](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#specifying-multiple-compose-files) I am able to find:

> You can supply multiple -f configuration files. When you supply
> multiple files, Compose combines them into a single configuration.
> Compose builds the configuration in the order you supply the files.
> Subsequent files override and add to their predecessors.

I read that "override and add to their predecessors" as meaning "some sections add, some sections override". I would like to know **which ones** add, and **which ones** override.

Comment: Sorry, almost the same comment as in your other question :-) : Why would you want to combine the docker-compose files? Being dependent of the Environment is not a valid reason (IMHO). It might be better to treat every docker-compose file as a service (or small set of services) of their own.

Answer (score 0):

See the ["Adding and overriding configuration" section of the "Extend services in Compose" page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration) (emphasis in original):

> For single-value options like `image`, `command` or `mem_limit`, the new value replaces the old value.
>
> For the **multi-value options** `ports`, `expose`, `external_links`, `dns`, `dns_search`, and `tmpfs`, Compose concatenates both sets of values.
>
> In the case of `environment`, `labels`, `volumes`, and `devices`, Compose “merges” entries together with locally-defined values taking precedence. For `environment` and `labels`, the environment variable or label name determines which value is used.
>
> Entries for `volumes` and `devices` are merged using the mount path in the container.

That page also has several examples.

This matches the behavior you're observing: if you have two files that both have `ports:` they simply get concatenated together, but if you have two files that both have `environment:` variables, the last definition for each individual variable takes effect.